# Why does MySQL 5.7 Even Scheduler START datetime not match with the CREATE/ALTER EVENT START time?

Tags: mysql, mysql-event

After I create the event...

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`abc`@`localhost` EVENT `testEventYearly` ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 YEAR STARTS '2018-01-01 00:00:00' ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE DO BEGIN
CALL `spTestEventYearly` ();
END$$
```

...I look in the `mysql.event` table and see a `starts` value of `2018-01-01 06:00:00`. I've checked the date/time on the server and all is well. Why is there a difference in time? And will it execute at `06:00` or `00:00`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html says:

> Times in the ON SCHEDULE clause are interpreted using the current session time_zone value. This becomes the event time zone; that is, the time zone that is used for event scheduling and is in effect within the event as it executes. **These times are converted to UTC and stored along with the event time zone in the mysql.event table.** This enables event execution to proceed as defined regardless of any subsequent changes to the server time zone or daylight saving time effects.

(emphasis mine)

I infer you are in the US Central time zone. You created the event when your local time zone was UTC -0600, and then the value stored in `mysql.event` was advanced six hours to UTC.